# What is the exact ratio of dark energy to mass?

Tags: energy, cosmology, mass, universe, dark-energy

I need to know the exact ratio between mass and dark energy (total dark energy in the universe / total mass in the universe). I could only find it to 2 decimal points (0.68). I need this to make this code (https://github.com/jordan663994/einstein-field-equation-solver/) more accurate.

Comment: You can look Planck 2018 best fit values (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06209.pdf), table 1 or 2. $\Omega_{\Lambda} = 0.6847$ (TT,TE,EE+lowE+lensing) or $\Omega_{\Lambda} = 0.6842$ (Plik Best Fit).

Comment: Is the ratio you are seeking the ratio between two Omega "density" parameters in the Friedmann equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation: Omega_k and Omega_Lambda. If this is what you seek, then the @seVenVold reference is what you want. However, for best detail you may need to also use the values for the other two Omega.

Comment: We don't know the "exact" ratio. There are even some physicists / cosmologists working on alternatives to general relativity who say dark energy doesn't exist.

Comment: To add a bit of clarification regarding Hammen's comment, nothing in physics is known with absolute certainty. Some near certainty "facts" create a probability confidence close to certainty, but never 100%. Generally, published numerical values have a plus-and-minus error range. As an example from 2018 Planck, Page 33, Equation 35: Ωm = 0.3081 ± 0.0065.